# Receiving FileNotFoundException (Access is denied) when using JAXB to marshal to File

Tags: java, jaxb

When I marshall to system.out. my List comes up in the console no problem. when I try to send it to a file I get an error saying

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
- with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\computerparts.xml (Access is denied)]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
at com.cooksys.assessment.List$2.doSaveCommand(List.java:201)
at com.cooksys.assessment.List$2.actionPerformed(List.java:179).....ETC
```

in my source I don't get any errors. below is my save(marshall) method

```
    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    doSaveCommand();
                } catch (JAXBException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            private void doSaveCommand() throws JAXBException {
                ArrayList<String> save = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < destination.size(); i++) {
                    save.add((String)destination.getElementAt(i));
                }
                ListWrapper Assembledparts = new ListWrapper();
                Assembledparts.setAssembledparts (save);

                File file = new File ("c:\\computerparts.xml");

                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListWrapper.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                marshaller.marshal(Assembledparts, System.out);

                marshaller.marshal(Assembledparts, file);
            }
        });
```

I would expect if I can get my list to show up in the console I should be able to marshal to a file. what am I missing? below is my getter setter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class ListWrapper {
@XmlElement(name = "part")
private  List<String> save;

public List<String> save() {
    if (save == null) {
        save = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    }
    return this.save;
}

public void setAssembledparts (ArrayList<String> save) {
    this.save = save;

   }
```

if needed main code is below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List implements ActionListener{

    JList destinationList, sourceList;
    JButton buttonin, buttonout;

    DefaultListModel source;
    static DefaultListModel destination;

    public JPanel createContentPane (){

        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

        source = new DefaultListModel();
        destination = new DefaultListModel();

        String shoppingItems[] =  {"Case", "Motherboard", "CPU", "RAM", "GPU",
        "HDD", "PSU"};

        for(int i = 0; i < shoppingItems.length; i++)
        {
            source.addElement(shoppingItems[i]);
        }

        destinationList = new JList(source);
        destinationList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        destinationList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        destinationList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
        destinationList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane list1 = new JScrollPane(destinationList);

        sourceList = new JList(destination);
        sourceList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        sourceList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        sourceList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
        sourceList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane list2 = new JScrollPane(sourceList);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonin = new JButton(">>");
        buttonin.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        buttonin.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonin);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list1);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);

                buttonout = new JButton("<<");
                buttonout.addActionListener(this);
                buttonPanel.add(buttonout);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list2);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

        totalGUI.add(bottomPanel);
        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    private JPanel createSquareJPanel(Color color, int size) {
        JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
        tempPanel.setBackground(color);
        tempPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        return tempPanel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        int i = 0;


        if(e.getSource() == buttonin)
        {
            int[] fromindex = destinationList.getSelectedIndices();
            Object[] from = destinationList.getSelectedValues();

            for(i = 0; i < from.length; i++)
            {
                destination.addElement(from[i]);
            }

            for(i = (fromindex.length-1); i >=0; i--)
            {
                source.remove(fromindex[i]);
            }
        }

        else if(e.getSource() == buttonout)
        {
            Object[] to = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
            int[] toindex = sourceList.getSelectedIndices();

            for(i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                source.addElement(to[i]);
            }

            for(i = (toindex.length-1); i >=0; i--)
            {
                destination.remove(toindex[i]);
            }
        }
    }



    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PC Parts Builder");
        JMenu file = new JMenu ("File");

        List demo = new List();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem item;
        file.add(item = new JMenuItem("Load"));
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {   
                doOpenCommand();
                } catch  (JAXBException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            private void doOpenCommand() throws JAXBException{

                File file = new File ("c:\\computerparts.xml" );

                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListWrapper.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshal = context.createUnmarshaller();
                ListWrapper assembledparts = (ListWrapper) unmarshal.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(assembledparts);
            }
        });

        mnFile.add(item);


        JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    doSaveCommand();
                } catch (JAXBException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            private void doSaveCommand() throws JAXBException {
                ArrayList<String> save = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < destination.size(); i++) {
                    save.add((String)destination.getElementAt(i));
                }
                ListWrapper Assembledparts = new ListWrapper();
                Assembledparts.setAssembledparts (save);

                File file = new File ("c:\\computerparts.xml");

                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListWrapper.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty     (Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                marshaller.marshal(Assembledparts, System.out);

                marshaller.marshal(Assembledparts, file);
            }



        });
        mnFile.add(mntmSave);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mnFile.add(mntmNewMenuItem);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to create a file in C: drive, the error message clearly says "Access Denied" Can you please check

Comment: I actually figured out about a minute after I posted this. thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\computerparts.xml (Access is denied)]

try to avoid c: and put source file in another folder, ie. c:/temp/FileName.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is the line to pay attention to:
`[java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\computerparts.xml (Access is denied)]`

Either computerparts.xml doesn't exist, or you don't have the permissions to write to it. Put that file elsewhere, and update the line `File file = new File ("c:\\computerparts.xml");` to point to the new file location.